# Syntax with BQL, with 2 where and multiples or

Tags: acumatica

I would like know what is the good syntax:

```
public PXProcessing<ABONNEMENT,
  Where<ABONNEMENT.abodatenextgeneration, GreaterEqual<Current<aboFilter.usrdatedeb>>,
  And<ABONNEMENT.abodatenextgeneration, LessEqual<Current<aboFilter.usrdatefin>>,
  And<Where<Current<aboFilter.usrClient>, IsNull,
  Or<ABONNEMENT.aboclt, Equal<Current<aboFilter.usrClient>>>>>,
  And<Where<Current<aboFilter.usrAnalytique>,IsNull,Or<ABONNEMENT.aboanalytique, 
  Equal<Current<aboFilter.usrAnalytique>>>>>>>> AbonnementList;
```

It's ok with 1 (And or) but not 2.

```
   public PXProcessing<ABONNEMENT,
      Where<ABONNEMENT.abodatenextgeneration, GreaterEqual<Current<aboFilter.usrdatedeb>>,
      And<ABONNEMENT.abodatenextgeneration, LessEqual<Current<aboFilter.usrdatefin>>,
      And<Where<Current<aboFilter.usrClient>, IsNull,
      Or<ABONNEMENT.aboclt, Equal<Current<aboFilter.usrClient>>>>>>>> AbonnementList;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Brackets<>` to chain your conditions.

```
public PXProcessing<ABONNEMENT,
    Where<Brackets<ABONNEMENT.abodatenextgeneration, GreaterEqual<Current<aboFilter.usrdatedeb>>,
        And<ABONNEMENT.abodatenextgeneration, LessEqual<Current<aboFilter.usrdatefin>>,
            And<Where<Current<aboFilter.usrClient>, IsNull>,
                Or<Brackets<ABONNEMENT.aboclt, Equal<Current<aboFilter.usrClient>>>>>,
            And<Where<Current<aboFilter.usrAnalytique>,IsNull>,Or<ABONNEMENT.aboanalytique, 
                Equal<Current<aboFilter.usrAnalytique>>>>>>>> AbonnementList;
```

Comment: Thanks Zoltan, I have this error : Using the generic type 'Brackets<TCondition>' requires 1 type arguments

Comment: It's ok with this, thanks Zoltan :

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Zoltan, with this syntax, everything is ok :

> ```
>    public PXProcessing<ABONNEMENT,
>                 Where <Brackets
>                       <ABONNEMENT.abodatenextgeneration.IsGreaterEqual<aboFilter.usrdatedeb.FromCurrent>>.
>                       And<ABONNEMENT.abodatenextgeneration.IsLessEqual<aboFilter.usrdatefin.FromCurrent>>
>                      
>                      .And<Where<aboFilter.usrAnalytique.FromCurrent.IsNull
>                      .Or<ABONNEMENT.aboanalytique.IsEqual<aboFilter.usrAnalytique.FromCurrent>>>>
>
>   
>                      .And<Where<aboFilter.usrClient.FromCurrent.IsNull
>                      .Or<ABONNEMENT.aboclt.IsEqual<aboFilter.usrClient.FromCurrent>>>>    
>                      >
>                >  AbonnementList;
> ```